# Webscraping Selenium / Handling PopUp-Windows?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriverwait

,i try to scrape something from a website and so far it works good - but in the (anonymous) selenium windows there is everytime poping up a message which i have to handle manually. So far i was not able to automatize this.

Message:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QAtMuzimJ3bLOfVEJY2M65S32nvc1Ewb/view?usp=sharing

Normaly i can click on a button when i copy the xpath like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="example-blabla"]').click ()
```

But in that case it is not working with this popup-windows - the xpath looks a little bit different...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/button').click ()
```

Also tried to work with window_handles but this also does not work... below you can find the whole code

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os


options = Options ()
#options.add_argument ('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome (os.getcwd () + '/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

link = "https://www.finanzen.net"
driver.get (link)
time.sleep (5)

a = driver.window_handles
print(a[0])
driver.switch_to.window(a[0])
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/button').click ()

driver.quit()
```

UPDATE - was able to find the solution as following which worked for me:

- save active window <driver.current_window_handle>
- switch to frame <driver.switch_to.frame ("sp_message_iframe_213940")>
- do the clicking
- and switch back to the "normal" window <driver.switch_to.window(act_window)

code as following:

```
link = "https://www.finanzen.net"
driver.get (link)
time.sleep (5)
act_window = driver.current_window_handle
driver.switch_to.frame ("sp_message_iframe_213940")
time.sleep (3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath
('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/button').click ()
print("Message should disappeared...")
time.sleep (3)
driver.switch_to.window(act_window)
print("Hurra!...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element present inside an `iframe`.You need to switch `iframe` first to access the button element.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()
and following css selector.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()
and following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='sp_message_iframe']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='OK und Weiterlesen']"))).click()
```

Import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```